# When applying filter to a scala Map, how can I also check what entries were removed?

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am learning scala, and at one point I want to remove entries from a map based on the value (not the key). I also want to know how many entries were removed - my program expects that exactly one entry should be removed.
Removing entries by their values can be done by applying filterNot, ok -- but how can I verify that exactly one entry was removed?

So far the only way I saw to achieve that is to run the predicate twice -- once for the "count" method (to count how often the predicate matches), and then with filterNot, to actually remove the entries.

What is the Scala way of achieving that in one go?

The only other solution I found is to first use filter(...) to get the values to be removed ,and then use "-" to throw out the elements by their keys - but again, this requires two runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you don't mind creating a collection out of the information that is removed you can use [`partition`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@partition(p:A=%3EBoolean):(Repr,Repr)):

```
scala> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> res0.partition { case (k, v) => v % 2 == 0 }
res3: (Map(2 -> 2),Map(1 -> 1, 3 -> 3))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best fit to what I want to achieve - partition() the original map, assign the second tuple element(the part where the predicate fails) to the map which I wanted to filter, and use the first tuple element to check how many elements were removed.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know if only one entry was removed then you can use size to get the size before and after the filter operation. The difference should be one.

```
scala> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> res0.filterNot { case (k, v) => v % 2 == 0 }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 3 -> 3)

scala> res0.size - res1.size
res2: Int = 1
```

Comment: This is not sufficient for me, because I also want to see what elements were removed, esp. in the case that more than one element was removed (I expect exactly one removed element).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `groupBy` on the mapped values, as follows; let

```
val a = ((1 to 3) zip (11 to 33)).toMap
a: Map(1 -> 11, 2 -> 12, 3 -> 13)
```

then

```
a.groupBy(_._2 % 2 == 0)
res: Map(false -> Map(1 -> 11, 3 -> 13), true -> Map(2 -> 12))
```

Comment: This would have worked for me, too. As the answer with the "partition" trick came first, this was the method I used, but "group by" would also fit the bill.